# Unable to find bundled Java Version Flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, macos

Estoy utilizando una MacBook Pro con sistema operativo Mojave estoy instalando todo lo necesario para trabajar con flutter en esta computadora, pero utilizar el comando flutter doctor -v para revisar que me ha faltado pues me marcan los siguientes errores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

del lado izquierdo he agregado el path para encontrar flutter y java pero me marca el error, Unable to find bundled Java Version
tengo instalado android studio, git, xcode , visual studio code.

Al modificar los datos en bash_profile al terminar siempre utilizo el comando  source ~/.bash_profile  para poder refrescar los cambios y aun así me da error.

el error de Android license status unknown me sigue apareciendo y yo ya instale  sdk command line tool(latest) desde android studio

Answer (score 0):

Los mismos errores te dan la solución, en la parte de Android Licenses tienes que ejecutar este comando:

```
 flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

y de ahí aceptas las licencias

En `iOS toolChain` tienes que ejecutar los comandos que te dejan debajo de cada error al igual que en los demás apartados en la parte de `To install:`

Y encontré un video que te puede ayudar a solucionar el problem de `unable to find bundled Java Version`, espero y te ayude:
[unable to find bundled Java Version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xnla17fdZ24)

Comment: Lo del video ya lo hice y al introducir el comando  ln -s ../jre jdk me dice File Exist y sigue marcando los mismo errores